# Caching tasks and removing them from the cache when faulted

Tags: c#, async-await, cache, exception

Is the code in Test1 and Test similar if it's being called like in `RunAsync`?

The example is simplified, but this is an application with a high concurrency during peak and does have performance problems.

- We can expect the caller will always use `await`.
- We try to prevent faulted Tasks to be cached.
- The idea is that it saves the "async statemachine" stuff for one function.

I know you always have to measure where the problems are, but if this is **free** performance gain I'd like to implement this in most of the caching.

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
    await Test1("a"); // this 
    await Test2("b"); // or this
}


private async Task<string> Test1(string key)
{
    try
    {
        return await GetFromCacheOrDbAsync(key);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Cache.Remove(key);
        throw;
    }
}


private Task<string> Test2(string key)
{
    var task = GetFromCacheOrDbAsync(key);

    if ( task.Exception != null )
    {
        Cache.Remove(key);
        throw task.Exception;
    }

    return task;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that here we are reviewing concrete code from a project? `Test1` and `Test2` do not seem to match this criteria.

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala, no I was not aware - I will move the question in that case. Do you think this is more something for SoftwareEngineering or Stackoverflow?

Comment: @DirikBoer I think SO might be a good place to ask.